# Équivalents d'un sens de « sketchy » et de l'emploi adjectival « sketch » : s'agit-il du même sens ?

Tags: traduction, adjectifs, québec, anglicismes

> ...l'avenir du faucon pèlerin demeure *sketch*. ([publicité](https://twitter.com/jfrobergeQc/status/1635968367726063618), Gouvernement du Québec)
> *This repair job is [sketchy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sketchy) at best.*

À la base, le [sketch](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sketch#Noun) c'est un croquis, une esquisse, une ébauche. L'emploi dans le premier exemple a valeur adjectivale.

- S'agit-il du même sens dans les deux cas ?
- Quels sont des équivalents en français pour les deux exemples ?

Answer (score 1):

Je ne comprenais pas le sens non plus, mise à part le fait que c'est négatif. Des articles de pressent qualifient d'ailleurs la campagne de "*un brin «sketch»*", en citant des réceptions assez négatives.

En fouillant un peu j'ai trouvé [ça](https://mauditsfrancais.ca/10-expressions-a-connaitre-se-fondre-paysage-quebecois/) :

> "C’est sketch" : En France, un sketch (selon Larousse) c’est une oeuvre dialoguée de courte durée, généralement comique, représentée au théâtre, au music-hall, à la télévision ou au cinéma. **Au Québec, cela signifie littéralement que “ça craint” voire même que c’est un peu “flippant”** (au sens français du terme). Concrètement, un restaurant dont la façade a mauvaise mine et à l’intérieur duquel on entend le personnel se taper dessus, c’est “sketch”. Ceci dit, cela peut aussi donner lieu à un sketch.

Il y a plusieurs sens à "ça craint", notamment simplement "c'est nul", ou "c'est dangereux, douteux, risqué" (un quartier qui craint). Je penche plutôt pour le deuxième sens. Appliqué à l'avenir du faucon pèlerin, je comprends le sens de "incertain, qui ne présage rien de bon".

Comment: _Incertain_ est utile. Avec un _brin_ (un peu), ça donne probablement _mal ficelé_ je dirais, mais je n'ai pas la phrase au complet. Le nom _sketch_ signifie aussi au Québec le petit dialogue de spectacle etc. j'en faisais à l'école primaire au Québec. Reste à comparer avec le _repair job_ qui est _sketchy_.